# Как из одного приложения обратиться к другому и получить данные?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

В одном приложении есть класс со значениями, там обрабатываются данные.

Как мне получить значения к элементам(желательно ссылку в памяти, а не копию), что б сразу видеть изменения в другом приложении.

Comment: Можно использовать атомы, файлы, реестр...обо всем этом нет смысла расписываться здесь. Обо всем можно почитать "в интернетах" =)

Answer (score 8):

Один из удобных способов - это использование именованных каналов. [Практическое руководство: использование именованных каналов для взаимодействия между процессами по сети.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb546085.aspx) Можно выбрать подходящий формат передачи данных, например, JSON или XML, сериализовать классы в этот формат и писать, читать их из канала.

Другой подход - это [отображаемые в память файлы](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997372.aspx). Добавив определенную синхронизацию (мьютексы и т.п.) можно перекидывать данные между процессами.